# Ruby on Rails - Database query in array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Okay, I am attempting to perform the following which I know how to do so in PHP but not in Ruby on Rails:

```
SELECT * FROM calls WHERE (status = 'open') OR (status = 'pending')
```

Simply look in the database in the calls table for open or pending status.

I'd like to do this in Rails. Currently I've got this in my controller:

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @calls = Call.all
  end
end
```

And this is my view:

```
<table>
  <% @cals.each do |call| %>
    <tr>
      <th><%= link_to call.id, call_path(call) %></th>
      <th><%= call.cname %></th>
      <th><%= call.cbn %></th>
      <th><%= call.email %></th>
      <th><%= call.operator  %></th>
      <th><%= call.reason  %></th>
      <th><%= call.ticket %></th>
      <th><%= call.created_at %></th>
      <th><%= call.tier %></th>
      <th><%= call.status %></th>
      <th><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_call_path(call) %></th>
      <th><%= link_to 'Remove', call_path(call), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></th>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that you've got an typo in your view. You're using the `@cals` instance variable there, but in your controller it's assigned as `@calls`.

Comment: Sorry. The full def index is actually.

'class CallsController < ApplicationController'
  'def index'
    '@calls = Call.all'
    '@cals = Call.all'

 end

The cals I am wanting to define the open or pending since I have two query's on the same page one to list only open or pending then another table for all.<br />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def index
  @calls = Call.where(status: ['open', 'pending'])
end
```

It's considered good practice to make sure these `where` calls don't leak into your controller, because they're exposing a lot of the internals of `Call`. You can define a scope inside the `Call` class:

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :open_or_pending, -> { where(status: ['open', 'pending']) }
end
```

And then use that inside your controller:

```
def index
  @calls = Call.open_or_pending
end
```

Note that now, the controller doesn't need to know that `Call` has a `status` field, and what its values can be.

Comment: + 1 Why is it preferred to have scopes rather than `where` clauses in the controller? Isn't it both unlikely to leak? The scope gets converted to the same SQL anyway.

Comment: Scopes provide encapsulation and reuse. Encapsulation is useful when the underlying database changes. With scopes, you'll only have to change the scopes, not the rest of the application. If there's a complex `where` chain, this could be moved into a single scope, and then be broken up into smaller scopes. The controller only needs to call the top level scope and not care about the complexity. Scopes also prevent you from having to repeat the `where` calls over and over. It's quite common for a `where` chain to be copy pasted to different places. If this happens, a scope is definitely required.

Comment: I love and appreciate scopes to keep my code dry. The point I didn't quite understand is the security issue, could you maybe share a link or explain further?